# error mismatched input '{' expecting <EOF> en un archivo json en un proyecto java

Tags: java, json

trato de llamar un archivo json en un proyecto, pero me sale el error en el objeto 2 del siguiente código
`{"spawnDate":1549148803531,"lifeTime":1,"id":1,"spawnRate":0.9748838375902849,"position":{"longitude":0.0,"latitude":0.0},"name":"Bulbasaur"}
{"spawnDate":1549148803576,"lifeTime":1,"id":2,"spawnRate":0.47975623338383155,"position":{"longitude":0.0,"latitude":0.0},"name":"Ivysaur"}
{"spawnDate":1549148803576,"lifeTime":1,"id":3,"spawnRate":0.43068114793980583,"position":{"longitude":0.0,"latitude":0.0},"name":"Venusaur"}
{"spawnDate":1549148803576,"lifeTime":1,"id":4,"spawnRate":0.16566267074044172,"position":{"longitude":0.0,"latitude":0.0},"name":"Charmander"}
{"spawnDate":1549148803577,"lifeTime":1,"id":5,"spawnRate":0.7449970075069223,"position":{"longitude":0.0,"latitude":0.0},"name":"Charmeleon"}
{"spawnDate":1549148803577,"lifeTime":1,"id":6,"spawnRate":0.5883550629876156,"position":{"longitude":0.0,"latitude":0.0},"name":"Charizard"}
{"spawnDate":1549148803577,"lifeTime":1,"id":7,"spawnRate":0.3070950852523471,"position":{"longitude":0.0,"latitude":0.0},"name":"Squirtle"}
{"spawnDate":1549148803578,"lifeTime":1,"id":8,"spawnRate":0.17378026621123432,"position":{"longitude":0.0,"latitude":0.0},"name":"Wartortle"}
{"spawnDate":1549148803578,"lifeTime":1,"id":9,"spawnRate":0.1507294754090891,"position":{"longitude":0.0,"latitude":0.0},"name":"Blastoise"}`

Answer (score 0):

La estructura de tu JSON esta mal ya que debes crea un `JSONArray` que los contenga, en un JSONArray separas los JSONObject por ",":

```
[
  {
    "spawnDate": 1549148803531,
    "lifeTime": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "spawnRate": 0.9748838375902849,
    "position": {
      "longitude": 0,
      "latitude": 0
    },
    "name": "Bulbasaur"
  },
  {
    "spawnDate": 1549148803576,
    "lifeTime": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "spawnRate": 0.47975623338383155,
    "position": {
      "longitude": 0,
      "latitude": 0
    },
    "name": "Ivysaur"
  },
  {
    "spawnDate": 1549148803576,
    "lifeTime": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "spawnRate": 0.43068114793980583,
    "position": {
      "longitude": 0,
      "latitude": 0
    },
    "name": "Venusaur"
  },
  {
    "spawnDate": 1549148803576,
    "lifeTime": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "spawnRate": 0.16566267074044172,
    "position": {
      "longitude": 0,
      "latitude": 0
    },
    "name": "Charmander"
  },
  {
    "spawnDate": 1549148803577,
    "lifeTime": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "spawnRate": 0.7449970075069223,
    "position": {
      "longitude": 0,
      "latitude": 0
    },
    "name": "Charmeleon"
  },
  {
    "spawnDate": 1549148803577,
    "lifeTime": 1,
    "id": 6,
    "spawnRate": 0.5883550629876156,
    "position": {
      "longitude": 0,
      "latitude": 0
    },
    "name": "Charizard"
  },
  {
    "spawnDate": 1549148803577,
    "lifeTime": 1,
    "id": 7,
    "spawnRate": 0.3070950852523471,
    "position": {
      "longitude": 0,
      "latitude": 0
    },
    "name": "Squirtle"
  },
  {
    "spawnDate": 1549148803578,
    "lifeTime": 1,
    "id": 8,
    "spawnRate": 0.17378026621123432,
    "position": {
      "longitude": 0,
      "latitude": 0
    },
    "name": "Wartortle"
  },
  {
    "spawnDate": 1549148803578,
    "lifeTime": 1,
    "id": 9,
    "spawnRate": 0.1507294754090891,
    "position": {
      "longitude": 0,
      "latitude": 0
    },
    "name": "Blastoise"
  }
]
```